# Retrieve information in SharePoint Online about office 365 hosting provider

Tags: office-365

Is it possible to retrieve information about the hosting provider of an office 365 environment from within SharePoint. I would like to know on which hosting provider my custom solution is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I undersand the question, the short answer is no.

The operations permitted in the Sandbox prevent network calls (no webservices) and won't allow you to deply code that interacts with the host.

Comment: i thought so. Any idea if this will change with the new SP version(2013)?

Comment: Highly doubtful that it will change with 2013. Although with the App model allowing you to have Azure hosted apps that are called out to you may be able to track where requests to the Azure hosted code is coming from. This is of course pure speculation.